# Convert Double to ArrayList - Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have a method that use ArrayList. But I got my accelerate-meter values as a Double. 
How can I convert a Double to ArrayList so I can find the peaks of *TotalAccelermeter* in my method I implemented. 
Thanks in advance. 
I have some other problems, like my List is float while I'm passing Double.

```
@Override
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // The light sensor returns a single value.
    // Many sensors return 3 values, one for each axis.

    double xx=event.values[0];
    double yy=event.values[1];
    double zz=event.values[2];
    double TotalAccelerate=Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xx, 2)
            +Math.pow(yy, 2)
            +Math.pow(zz, 2)));
    sensorText.setText("Total: " + TotalAccelerate);
    Log.i(DEBUG,"Total "+ TotalAccelerate);
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    list.toArray(TotalAccelerate);

    findPeaks(TotalAccelerate);
  }


//Find peak values.
    public static ArrayList<Float> findPeaks(List<Float> points) {
    ArrayList<Float> peaks = new ArrayList<Float>();

    if (points == null || points.size() < 1)
        return peaks;

    float x1_n_ref = 0;
    int alpha = 0; //0=down, 1=up.
    int size = points.size();// -1)/100;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 5) {
        float IndexValues = points.get(i);
        if (IndexValues > 140) {
            float delta = x1_n_ref - IndexValues;
            if (delta < 0) {
                x1_n_ref = IndexValues;
                alpha = 1;

            } else if (alpha == 1 && delta > 0) {
                peaks.add(x1_n_ref);

                alpha = 0;
            }

        } else if (alpha == 0) {
            x1_n_ref = IndexValues;
        }
    }

    return peaks;
}
```

Comment: To add a value to your list use the .add method: `list.add(TotalAccelerate)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never actually add the TotalAccelerate value to the ArrayList (list). You can do that with the ArrayList's add method:

```
list.add(TotalAccelerate);
```

As you mentioned in your post, you have another problem with the call to the findPeaks method. The method takes an `ArrayList<Float>` and you intend to pass the `ArrayList<Double>` to it. Replace this:

```
findPeaks(TotalAccelerate);
```

with this:

```
findPeaks(list);
```

You'll need to change your method signature for findPeaks to take an `ArrayList<Double>`. Inside the method, if you need a Float instead, you'll need to cast the value from a Double to a Float.

Hopefully, this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was helpful. I also made my threshold **if (IndexValues > 9)** instead of 140. I think my algorithm is now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
arrayList.add(Float.valueOf(String.valueOf(your_double_variable)));
```